# Responsive menu not displaying full height 100%

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using a responsive menu (script by dbushell), I have set it up on my temporary host:

http://saltz987.web1337.net/test.html

if you shrink the width of the browswer the 3 bar menu icon is displayed and when you click it the menu opens up. Here you will see links from chapter 1 to chapter 17.

The problem I have is that the menu is not 100% of the page but is the height of the main content please can anyone help me with getting the menu to display the full 100% height.

I have tried setting the nav to:

```
height:100%;
```

without luck.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the HTML and body to 100%. Also add max-height 100% to avoid overflow problems in the future.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
.nav {
    height:100%;
}
```

You need to expand the div in which the nav resides, in this case `#inner-wrap` .

```
@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
    div#inner-wrap {
        height:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried setting these but did not help. I have set up a fiddle if it makes it easier: http://jsfiddle.net/6wrAt/2/, but to see the code not working properly you will need to break out the frame: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6wrAt/2/show/

Comment: Hi @Vector thanks for the help, also #outer-wrap {height: 100%;} was needed. Once again thanks :)